# Collect rows from spark DataFrame into JSON object, then put the object to another DF

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark DataFrame which contains some application usage data.
I'm aiming to collect certain metrics from this DataFrame, and then accumulate them together.

For instance, I may want to obtain a total number of users of my product in this DataFrame:

```
df.select($"user").count.distinct
100500
```

And then I want to builds stats across different application versions

```
df.groupBy("version").count.toJSON.show(false)

+-----------------------------------------+
|value                                    |
+-----------------------------------------+
|{"version":"1.2.3.4","count":4051}  |
|{"version":"1.2.3.5","count":1}     |
|{"version":"1.2.4.6","count":1}     |
|{"version":"2.0.0.1","count":30433} |
|{"version":"3.1.2.3","count":112195}|
|{"version":"3.1.0.4","count":11457} |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

Then I'd like to squash the records in the second DF, *so in the end I need to have an object like this*:

```
{ "totalUsers":100500, "versions":[
  {"version":"1.2.3.4","count":4051},
  {"version":"1.2.3.5","count":1},
  {"version":"1.2.4.6","count":1},
  {"version":"2.0.0.1","count":30433},
  {"version":"3.1.2.3","count":112195},
  {"version":"3.1.0.4","count":11457}] }
```

Then this object **shall be written to another spark DF**.

What could be the right way to implement this?

Disclaimer: I'm quite new to spark, so I'm sorry if my question is too noobish.
I've read a plenty of similar questions, including seemingly similar ones like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48252573/convert-spark-dataframe-with-schema-to-dataframe-of-json-string) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35227796/how-to-convert-spark-dataframe-output-to-json). The latter is close, but still doesn't give a clue on how to accumulate multiple rows into one object. Neither was I able to understand it from the [Apache Spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/).

Comment: So, you want to end up with single instance of object `{ "totalUsers":100500, "versions":[. ...}` ???

Comment: @nabongs yep, exactly.

Comment: @VasiliyGalkin please see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46482058/apache-spark-concatenate-multiple-rows-into-list-in-single-row

Comment: @statut Thanks for the link. However, it explains how to concatenate data between multiple columns, while I'm looking for rows concatenation.

Comment: @VasiliyGalkin can you post the original dataframe (df) ? some sample lines would help us test and give you correct solution

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [collect_list](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#collect_list-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-) function, for example:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
totalUsers = 100500
agg = df.groupBy().agg(F.collect_list("value").alias('versions')).withColumn("totalUsers", lit(totalUsers)).show()
```

Where `df` is data frame with aggregated versions. I get the following result:

```
+--------------------+----------+
|            versions|totalUsers|
+--------------------+----------+
|[{"version":"1.2....|    100500|
+--------------------+----------+
```

My example is written in Python but I believe the same approach you can use for your language.